# actions on google, Oauth account Linking

Tags: oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, account-linking

I have been trying to connect an assistant action to my backend server
I am using  my own Oauth server and followed the instructions on 
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2?oauth=code
I am using actions_intent_Sign_in for my dialogflow event intent (like https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.signin.html)
when i use my action to sign in, i get the login window to my server, i do the account linking and i can see that i generated the tokens on my server but i cant find the token in (conv.user.access.token)

and this is the code for my intent using "actions on google sdk "

```js
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');

var path = require('path')
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json());

var server = http.createServer(expressApp).listen(3000)

const {
    dialogflow,
    SignIn
} = require('actions-on-google');


const app = dialogflow({
    debug: true,
    clientId: '7b4a6dfc-4b35-11e9-8646-d663bd873d93'
});

app.intent('Start Sign-in', conv => {
    conv.ask(new SignIn());
});

app.intent('Get Sign-in', (conv, params, signin) => {
    console.log("get sign in ");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(signin));
    if (signin.status === 'OK') {
        const access = conv.user.access.token 
        console.log("the access token is " + access);
        conv.ask('Great, thanks for signing in! What do you want to do next?');
    } else {
        conv.ask('I wont be able to save your data, but what do you want to do next?.');
    }
});
```

and the response comes back as

```js
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValue","status":"OK"}
the access token is undefined
Response {
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  "body": {
    "payload": {
      "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Great, thanks for signing in! What do you want to do next?"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the user object of conv has only this data

```js
"user": {
    "raw": {
      "lastSeen": "2019-03-20T12:46:23Z",
      "locale": "en-US",
      "userId": "okdhyeGSk5tofgLjEepIUrA6mmewCESY8MjklZRPvQJgv6-uybfPobwdfgtrGZJ3bE2sM9ninhst"
    },
    "storage": {},
    "_id": "okdhyeGSk5tofgLjEepIUrA6mmewCESY8MjklZRPvQJgv6-uybfPobwdfgtrGZJ3bE2sM9ninhst",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "permissions": [],
    "last": {
      "seen": "2019-03-20T12:46:23.000Z"
    },
    "name": {},
    "entitlements": [],
    "access": {},
    "profile": {}
  }
```

i dont know where the access/refresh token can be found or if there is any requirement for the post to send from my oauth server that i missed

Comment: how do i get client id, not showing in action page

Answer (score 0):

so finally i managed to get it working with the help of Actions on Google Support Team

the problem was me having another google account logged-in in another tab, even though i had the AoG and dialogflow agent connected with the same account

tried all using incognito window and it works